# Limit to the number switch/if options?

Tags: java

**Small disclaimer** I am new to Java and this is my first real programme i am trying to write.

I am currently writing a programme with 3 class's. The first is a GUI with a JComboBox, 4 JButtons and 20 JTextFields.

The second takes information from the JComboBox box and uses it to give labels to the 4 JButtons using a set of if statements.

The third populates the JTextFields when one of the the JButtons is clicked depending on the button clicked and the choice in the JComboBox using a set of switch statements.

The first 2 class's work fine and the third works fine until i enter x amount of switches and then i start to get an error.

A small example of my code for the third class is

```
switch (hiddenText) {
        case "Abecean Longfin":
        if (command.equals("Weakness to Frost")){
        gui.r1.setText("Elves Ear");
        gui.r2.setText("Fire Salts");
        gui.r3.setText("Ice Wraith Teeth");
        gui.r4.setText("White Cap");
        gui.r5.setText("");
        gui.r6.setText("");
        gui.r7.setText("");
        gui.r8.setText("");
        gui.r9.setText("");
        gui.r10.setText("");
        gui.r11.setText("");
        gui.r12.setText("");
        gui.r13.setText("");
        gui.r14.setText("");
        gui.r15.setText("");
        gui.r16.setText("");
        gui.r17.setText("");
        gui.r18.setText("");
        gui.r19.setText("");
        gui.r20.setText("");

        }
        if (command.equals("Fortify Sneak")){
        gui.r1.setText("Beehive Husk");
        gui.r2.setText("Frost Mirriam");
        gui.r3.setText("Hawk Feathers");
        gui.r4.setText("Human Flesh");
        gui.r5.setText("Powdered Mammoth Tusk");
        gui.r6.setText("Purple Mountain Flower");
        gui.r7.setText("");
        gui.r8.setText("");
        gui.r9.setText("");
        gui.r10.setText("");
        gui.r11.setText("");
        gui.r12.setText("");
        gui.r13.setText("");
        gui.r14.setText("");
        gui.r15.setText("");
        gui.r16.setText("");
        gui.r17.setText("");
        gui.r18.setText("");
        gui.r19.setText("");
        gui.r20.setText("");
        }
        if (command.equals("Weakness to Poison")){
        gui.r1.setText("Bleeding Crown");
        gui.r2.setText("Chaurus Eggs");
        gui.r3.setText("Deathbell");
        gui.r4.setText("Giant Lichen");
        gui.r5.setText("Pine Thrush Egg");
        gui.r6.setText("Sabre Cat Tooth");
        gui.r7.setText("Small Antlers");
        gui.r8.setText("");
        gui.r9.setText("");
        gui.r10.setText("");
        gui.r11.setText("");
        gui.r12.setText("");
        gui.r13.setText("");
        gui.r14.setText("");
        gui.r15.setText("");
        gui.r16.setText("");
        gui.r17.setText("");
        gui.r18.setText("");
        gui.r19.setText("");
        gui.r20.setText("");
        }
        if (command.equals("Fortify Restoration")){
        gui.r1.setText("Cyrodilic Spadetail");
        gui.r2.setText("Salt Pile");
        gui.r3.setText("Small Antlers");
        gui.r4.setText("Small Pearl");
        gui.r5.setText("");
        gui.r6.setText("");
        gui.r7.setText("");
        gui.r8.setText("");
        gui.r9.setText("");
        gui.r10.setText("");
        gui.r11.setText("");
        gui.r12.setText("");
        gui.r13.setText("");
        gui.r14.setText("");
        gui.r15.setText("");
        gui.r16.setText("");
        gui.r17.setText("");
        gui.r18.setText("");
        gui.r19.setText("");
        gui.r20.setText("");
        }
        break;
```

There are a total of 92 cases, each with 4 if statements and the programme works fine until i get to 57 cases and 2 if statements then i get an error symbol in the class tab title in IDE (using NetBeans) but not within the code itself.

When i compile and run the code i get an error box appearing saying "One or more projects compiled with errors" but if i choose to run anyway the programme will run fine as far as i have seen.

I have tried writing the code in various ways.e.g. originally using if statements and originally having class 2 and 3 as the same class and i always get this error at reaching x amount of choices.

In previous versions i would sometimes get the error symbol appear in the class tab title in the IDE and not within the code as usual but when trying to run the programme it wouldn 't run at all and gave some classpath error which i can't seem to reproduce now so can't post the exact code.

From the testing i have done.e.g. removing different sections of code it appears that it happens when x amount of choices are added.i.e. i can add the 52nd case and 3rd if statement and the error appears but if i remove a previous if statement so there are 52 cases and 2 if statements still then everything if fine.

From experimenting it would seem there is a limit to the amount of switches/if statements i can use although from looking around i could in theory have an infinite amount?

So my question is, is there a limit to the amount of switches/if statements i can use or is there something else going on which is causing an error when i enter x number of switches/if statements?

Comment: Well first of all if you are writing that many if statements there is something horribly wrong. I understand that this is your first program, but I just wanted to let you know that you do not have to suffer typing that much.

Comment: trololol, Skyrim alchemy, huh.

Answer (score 1):

you need to separate your data from your code.   stick all that data in a combination of maps and lists and use some simple, common code to update the gui elements.

```
// setup data code
List<String> elements = Arrays.asList("Elves Ear", "Fire Salts", ...);
Map<String,List<String>> elementMap;
elementMap.put("Weakness to Frost");

// setup ui code
List<String> elements = elementMap.get(command);
initUI(elements);

public void initUI(List<String> elements) {
  gui.r1.setText(elements.get(0));
  // ...
}
```

note, you could keep all your text fields in a List, and then the update code is:

```
public void initUI(List<String> elements) {
  for(int i = 0; i< textFields.size(); ++i) {
    textFields.get(i).setText(elements.get(i));
  }
}
```

in general, if you find yourself writing a lot of repetitive code, you are probably doing it wrong.

also, as @thatidiotguy pointed out in the comments, as you advance, you could move the data out of code like my example and into some sort of separate config file.

Comment: @thatidiotguy - indeed.  however, i wanted to go with baby-steps.  introduction file io at this point may be a bit much. :)

Comment: Java actually makes file io trivial. Personally I think it would be easier than learning the API for a ton of java.util objects which are huge java library classes. See java.util.Scanner if you want to take a look. EDIT - Whoops you are not OP. Still Scanner is not too bad.

Comment: @thatidiotguy - not sure that Scanner and file io is simpler than hard-coded lists.  file io in java is simpler than some languages, certainly, but not sure if i would say it is "trivial".

Comment: Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("myNumbers"));
      while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
          String line = sc.nextLine();
      }   Surely it is debatable, but it cannot get any simpler ya know?

Comment: @thatidiotguy - again, i'm not arguing that it's not reasonably easy (assuming knowledge of the API, of course).  i'm using a definition of simple compatible with someone who is coding for their first time and still working on basic loops.